# Store filter not working ExtJs 4.2.2

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to apply a date filter on a date column on an ext grid.
I can only get the filter to apply when i use `filterBy`, is this a bug in ext or am I doing something wrong?

```
var filterId = "myDateField"

var filterFn = function(record) {
    var recordDate = record.get(filterId);
    recordDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return recordDate.getTime() === value.getTime();
};

var filter = Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter',
{
    id: filterId,
    filterFn: filterFn
});

gridStore.filterBy(filterFn);  //works
gridStore.filter(filter);      //filterFn doesn't get called
gridStore.addFilter(filter);   //filterFn doesn't get called
```

EDIT:

I had `remoteFilter:true` set on my store which was causing my problem. Thanks Evan Trimboli

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ppt

Comment: Is your store configured with `remoterFilter: true` ?

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to be modifying the record data during a filtering operation.

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ppq

Comment: I had remote filter = true, thanks. If you put that as the answer I'll accept